# TFS build issues warnings for Orchard nunit test cases

Tags: tfs, nunit, orchardcms

I have a CI build configured on TFS online for an Orchard project I am working on.
The build can locate and run all the test cases. Some of the test cases end up with warnings as below.

I am not sure of the origin of the issue and "always there google" is not my friend either in this case.

```
No source data found for Orchard.Tests.Modules.Scripting.Dlr.EvaluatorTests.EvaluateBooleanExpression

No source data found for Orchard.Tests.Modules.Scripting.Dlr.EvaluatorTests.EvaluateBooleanExpression0

No source data found for Orchard.Tests.Modules.Scripting.Dlr.EvaluatorTests.EvaluateComplexMethodCall

No source data found for Orchard.Tests.Modules.Scripting.Dlr.EvaluatorTests.EvaluateComplexMethodCall2

No source data found for Orchard.Tests.Modules.Scripting.Dlr.EvaluatorTests.EvaluateComplexMethodCall3

No source data found for Orchard.Tests.Modules.Scripting.Dlr.EvaluatorTests.EvaluateComplexMethodCall4

No source data found for Orchard.Tests.Modules.Scripting.Dlr.EvaluatorTests.EvaluateComplexMethodCall5

No source data found for Orchard.Tests.Modules.Scripting.Dlr.EvaluatorTests.EvaluateComplexMethodCall6

No source data found for Orchard.Tests.Modules.Scripting.Dlr.EvaluatorTests.EvaluateConvertingBooleanExpression
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When tests are implemented in an abstract class and inherited by a test fixture, this warning shows up. This is an issue with the NUnit test runner. The tests will still run fine.

[Github Issue](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiB7dPz07nNAhVPxCYKHUJMC_sQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fnunit%2Fnunit-vs-adapter%2Fissues%2F6&usg=AFQjCNHj7URe5S0NvM5GW41SLGfbM9Rs9Q)